# Color distortion in CGImageCreate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, camera, cgimage

I am trying to build a image capture for my iOS app, but I keep getting color distortion on my CGImage result. Here is the camera preview, right colors.

[image]

Cola is red, all is well.

When I run my snapshot code, I get this :

[image]

Cola is blue... where did this come from?

I tried messing with some of the parameters, but only end up getting no image at all. Here is my snapshot code :

```
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = [cameraVideo bufRowBytes];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, [cameraVideo bufDataPtr], [cameraVideo bufWidth]*[cameraVideo bufHeight]*4, NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentPerceptual;

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate( [cameraVideo bufWidth], [cameraVideo bufHeight], bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel,
                                        bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
```

I am at my wits end, so if anyone can see what I am doing wrong, please let me know.

**FIXED**

Here is the final code:

```
if (cameraVideo.ARPixelFormat == kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB) {
    bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst;
} else {
    bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like your R (red) and B (blue) channels are swapped.  The camera is filling the buffer in BGR order, but you're telling the `CGImage` that the data is in `RGB` order.  I believe you control this using one of the `kCGBitmapByteOrder...` constants in your `CGBitmapInfo`.  Try setting `bitmapInfo` like this:

```
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;
```

If that doesn't work, try the other `kCGBitmapByteOrder...` constants (`kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little`, `kCGBitmapByteOrder16Big`, `kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little`).

### EDIT

Apple's SquareCam sample project has a file named `SquareCam/SqareCamViewController.m` (yes, “Square” is misspelled in the filename).  It contains this code:

```
    sourcePixelFormat = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType( pixelBuffer );
    if ( kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB == sourcePixelFormat )
        bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst;
    else if ( kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA == sourcePixelFormat )
        bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst;
    else
        return -95014; // only uncompressed pixel formats
```

You might want to do the same thing.

Comment: +1. Good problem diagnosis! Hopefully, this will fix the OP's question tidily. :)

Comment: Rob, are there any other techniques for figuring out the byte order of `CGImage` besides looking at bitmap and alpha info? I'm getting [wrong endianness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320474/getting-pixel-format-from-cgimage) when working with loaded png / jpeg via `NSImage` and stuck on figuring out what's happening.